# SQL select statement with a group clause?

Tags: sql-server, select, group-by

I am not sure how to go about this select statement.

```
table1
----------
t1id |  t1field1  |  t1field2

table2
----------
t2id |  t1id  |  t2field1  |  

outputTable3
----------
t1id  |  t2field1(row1)  |t2field1(row2) | t2field1 (row...)
```

My current results ouput (not what I want)

```
outputTable3
----------
t1id  |  t2field1(row1)
t1id  |  t2field1(row2)
t1id  |  t2field1(row...)
```

Comment: Search for `Dynamic Pivot` in Sql Server.

Comment: This has been asked and answered hundreds and hundreds of times.